# How to get the value a form field which name and id is dynamic

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I'm new with Sharepoint 2013 AND .NET c# so take it easy guys.

I'm writing a webpart which generates input forms dynamically. Each form may have different fields so field names/IDs are defined on runtime.

This is the code I generate a input text. `fieldname` is my variable here which is the ID and preferably the name of the input box. `fieldtitle` is the display name and `fielddefaultvalue` is the default value. This code part is in a loop and adds all inputs into `PlaceHolder1` every time.

```
TextBox formfield = new TextBox();
formfield.ID = fieldname;
formfield.Text = fielddefaultvalue;
formfield.Attributes.Add("placeholder", fieldtitle);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(formfield);
```

What my problem is, when I run this, name and ID of my input fields become like

`ctl00$ctl39$g_76a6fb01_d2b4_4087_a988_8b34b95dc136$Email`

I tried to get submitted values using

`Page.Request.Form["Email"]`

but no success. I guess it needs all those random characters too.

I could also use `Email.Text` to get value but `Email` part is dynamic and comes from a variable. Is there a way to use variable `fieldname` which contains `Email` and other field names as string?

How can I get submitted values and/or put clean names to my input fields.

Remember my field names are dynamic and kept in `fieldname` variable every round of the for loop.

**Edit**

After I submit form, this is the debug screen of `Page.Request.Form` . I don't know how/where I can find that random/unique string at the beginning of each input field. `flexiforms_xxx` part is the actual filed name.

[image]

Comment: I am not a web guy but cant we set ClientIDMode to static these days?

Comment: @danish that didn't help input fileds still have unique names. Added screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cache the TextBoxes in a dictionary when adding them:

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> textBoxesByFieldName = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();

foreach(string fieldName in FieldNames){
   TextBox formfield = new TextBox();
   formfield.ID = fieldname;
   formfield.Text = fielddefaultvalue;
   formfield.Attributes.Add("placeholder", fieldtitle);
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(formfield);
   textBoxesByFieldName.Add(fieldname, formfield);
}
```

And when you need them access the TextBox this way:

```
private TextBox GetTextBoxByFieldName(string fieldName){
   TextBox textBox;
   return textBoxesByFieldName.TryGetValue(fieldName, out textBox) ? textBox : null;
}
```

**[edit]** If I understand correctly you want to submit the form and get all the entered text for your clean field names:

```
void OnSubmitButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(KeyValuePair<string, TextBox> keyValue in textBoxesByFieldName){
      string fieldName = keyValue.Key;
      string fieldValue = keyValue.Value.Text; 
   }
}
```

**[edit2]** Above solution requires `formfield.AutoPostBack=true;` to be set

To avoid page refreshes, use `string fieldValue = Page.Request.Form[((System.Web.UI.Control)(keyValue.Value)).UniqueID];`

Comment: I tried this but values are empty. I need to get values when form is submitted not when it's created. I mean on button_click I need to use my clean fieldnames, not those random numbers, and get values submitted by end user.

Comment: @Ergec I've edited the answer. Hope I understood what you want to do

Comment: nope that didn't help. Main problem is my input filed names are strange. If they'd be regular names I could get them easily. I added a screenshot how my input fields' names are.

Comment: @Ergec Yes, SP dynamically generates those IDs (btw if you change your page layout, these IDs might change as well). Where does your fieldname come from? Isn't it the one you want to use? I never access the generated ID in my example.

Comment: yes I know that ID may change on different pages. If I can find that ID somewhere saved and combine with my variables while saving fields to dictionary, that would be awesome.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You know what fieldname you want to use; you can add it as described to the dictionary without having to access the generated one and retrieve it later. You could add some more code showing where the fieldname is coming from and how you want to use it when the button is being clicked.

Comment: Ok found it. Your edit has `fieldValue = keyValue.Value.Text` which returns empty instead I used `fieldValue = Page.Request.Form[((System.Web.UI.Control)(keyValue.Value)).UniqueID];` and Voilà it worked. If you update your answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Could you try keeping `string fieldValue = keyValue.Value.Text;` and add `formfield.AutoPostBack=true;` when initializing the TextBox? It looks cleaner to me

Comment: That works too but I didn't like page refresh on every change, visitors won't like this either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: formfield.ClientId

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form[...] requires the **name** or **index** of the control, so set the Name of the control

```
formfield.Name = fieldname;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Generated fieldnames are not simple like `Email` etc. They are like `ctl00$ctl39$g_76a6fb01_d2b4_4087_a988_8b34b95dc136$Email` . This is how it's generated so I can't get them using `Page.Request.Form["Email"]` . Either I need to find a way to override my input names to be simple or find a way to get that unique ID that is generated and use Request.Form

Comment: use `formfield.ClientIDMode = System.Web.UI.ClientIDMode.Static` but make the id less generic than 'email' it might clash with other components on the page.

Comment: nope I already tried that, and fieldnames are generic too. still input field names are auto-generated

Comment: Something must be forcing the clientIdMode...just iterate the Forms collection and find the keys that contain your unique id